# SQLite fetch returns null when the column is empty but I need it to return "" when the column is empty

Tags: php, sqlite

In PHP, SQLITE, I have the following code:

```
 public function queryRecord_GetRecord_M2ID_M3ID_All($M4_M2,$M4_M3) 
        {
            try 
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM M4 "
                        . "WHERE M4_M2 = :M4_M2 AND M4_M3 = :M4_M3 ";

                $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

                $stmt->bindValue(':M4_M2', $M4_M2);
                $stmt->bindValue(':M4_M3', $M4_M3);

                $stmt->execute();

                $mRecords = [];
                while($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {

                    echo "\n row['M4_Image1'] ======> {$row['M4_Image1']}\n";
                    if ($row['M4_Image1'] === NULL)
                    {
                        $row['M4_Image1'] = "";
                    }


                    $mRecords[] = [ 
                        'M4_M2'        => $row['M4_M2'],
                        'M4_M3'        => $row['M4_M3'],
                        'M4_Barcode'   => $row['M4_Barcode'],
                        'M4_Enable'    => $row['M4_Enable'],
                        'M4_Name'      => $row['M4_Name'],
                        'M4_Price'     => $row['M4_Price'],
                        'M4_Discount'  => $row['M4_Discount'],
                        'M4_Image1'    => $row['M4_Image1'],
                        'M4_Image2'    => $row['M4_Image2'],
                        'M4_Image3'    => $row['M4_Image3'],
                        'M4_Image4'    => $row['M4_Image4'],
                        'M4_Image5'    => $row['M4_Image5'],
                        'M4_Image6'    => $row['M4_Image6'],
                        'M4_Image7'    => $row['M4_Image7'],
                        'M4_Image8'    => $row['M4_Image8'],
                        'M4_Image9'    => $row['M4_Image9'],
                        'M4_Image10'   => $row['M4_Image10'],
                        'M4_A'         => $row['M4_A'],
                        'M4_B'         => $row['M4_B'],
                        'M4_C'         => $row['M4_C'],
                        'M4_D'         => $row['M4_D'],
                        'M4_E'         => $row['M4_E'],
                        'M4_F'         => $row['M4_F'],
                        'M4_G'         => $row['M4_G'],
                        'M4_H'         => $row['M4_H'],
                        'M4_I'         => $row['M4_I'],
                        'M4_J'         => $row['M4_J']                           
                    ];
                }
                return $mRecords;
            } 
            catch (\PDOException $e) 
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
```

if M4_Image1 column is empty, null is returned so I wrote the following code:

```
 if ($row['M4_Image1'] === NULL)
  {
     $row['M4_Image1'] = "";
  }
```

If I don't write this code, then I will have "null" string for M4_Image1 part of $mRecords

How can I have "" instead of null when the column of M4_Image1 is empty?
In this way I don't have to write a code to covert null to ""

Edit:

```
I added the database create too :  
    class SQLiteCreateDatabase 
    {
        private $pdo;

        public function __construct($pdo) {
            $this->pdo = $pdo;
        }

        public function createTable() {
            try 
            {
                $commands = [
                    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS M4 (
                            M4_M2       TEXT,
                            M4_M3       TEXT,
                            M4_Barcode  TEXT,
                            M4_Enable   TEXT,
                            M4_Name     TEXT,
                            M4_Price    TEXT,
                            M4_Discount TEXT,
                            M4_Image1   TEXT,
                            M4_Image2   TEXT,
                            M4_Image3   TEXT,
                            M4_Image4   TEXT,
                            M4_Image5   TEXT,
                            M4_Image6   TEXT,
                            M4_Image7   TEXT,
                            M4_Image8   TEXT,
                            M4_Image9   TEXT,
                            M4_Image10  TEXT,
                            M4_A        TEXT,
                            M4_B        TEXT,
                            M4_C        TEXT,
                            M4_D        TEXT,
                            M4_E        TEXT,
                            M4_F        TEXT,
                            M4_G        TEXT,
                            M4_H        TEXT,
                            M4_I        TEXT,
                            M4_J        TEXT
                            )'//,
                           //'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_positions_title ON M4 (M4_M2,M4_M3,M4_Barcode)'
                ];
                foreach ($commands as $command) {
                    $this->pdo->exec($command);
                }
                return TRUE;
            } 
            catch (\PDOException $e) 
            {
               return FALSE;   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It depends on what is written in you database. Maybe your Database Column should be declared as `NOT NULL DEFAULT ''`

Comment: I added the database create too as edit

Comment: You could use the null coalescing operator to simplify the code e.g. `'M4_Image1'    => $row['M4_Image1'] ?? '',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL databases, columns are nullable per default. So if if a row is added without a value for this field, `null` is saved and returned. You can prevent that by not making the column nullable:

```
M4_M2       TEXT NOT NULL
```

In this case, you always need to give a value when creating a new row. Or you can specify a default value for that column:

```
M4_M2       TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ""
```

With that, you will return empty string per default.

Answer (score 0):

In `sqlite3,python` i was facing  issue on '`null`' values in column in a table was returning as `None`.
Below activity in details:

`Column` added was of type `Text` by `alter` command:

```
ALTER TABLE <tableName>
   ADD Expertise Text;
```

So, i dropped column and made changes in column by adding default value to column as `""` :

```
ALTER TABLE <tableName> 
   DROP COLUMN <colname>

ALTER TABLE <tableName>
   ADD <colname> Text NOT NULL DEFAULT "";
```

Now all value will not be null but `""`.
It resolves the issue now  and returning value is not '`None`' but `""` (empty)